# Vocalised Arabic changes baselines in tabular environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, polyglossia

Using `polyglossia` I often set an Arabic text opposite and English text, and I want the baselines to match vertically within a tabular environment.  Sometimes the Arabic text is vocalised, and sometimes it is not.

In the following MWE, if the Arabic has no vocalisation, I can align it approximately with the English.  My first problem is why the Arabic is slightly below the English, instead of exactly aligned.

In the second paragraph, where the Arabic is vocalised, the Arabic baseline is nowhere near the English baseline.  This is the second problem.

What am I doing wrong?

The fonts are relatively unimportant in the MWE, the problem lies elsewhere.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.50]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin, Scale = 1]{Times}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.4}\selectfont
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.45\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
\end{Arabic} &
\begin{english}
Word word word Word word word Word  
\end{english}
\\
\begin{Arabic}
كلمةٍ كلمةً كلمةٌ كلمةٍ كلمةً كلمةٌ كلمةٍ كلمةً 
\end{Arabic} &
\begin{english}
Word word word Word word word Word word 
\end{english}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i haven't got an answer for you, but will only note that when a box is put around an english word extending to the default height and depth relative to the baseline, the "free space" on top and bottom are about equal.  when arabic is vocalized, the height can increase rather dramatically, and may exceed the above-baseline height for english (or most other western languages).  add a couple of (english) parentheses into the mix, and a couple of letters with descenders, to show the full vertical extent of the english, then try the parens with the arabic to see the comparable effect.

Comment: yes, it's dramatic

Comment: If you  define arabic as default language you can dispense with `Arabic` environment.  In your case you can  use `setspace`  package to manually modify space between baselines  in the english text to  match vertically with baselines of arabic text